# Using FME to write to variable output files?

Tags: fme-form, dgn, files

In FME (2016.1), I am combining data from 10 shape files to one big layer, and want to write those to a DGN file. But only for a variable area name. There are more area names in the combined shape files, and per area I want to create a DGN with that area name as filename.

Can this be done in FME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think you need is called a "fanout" in FME.

A fanout creates separate outputs depending on the value of an attribute or other value. There are two types of fanout. The Feature Type Fanout would create a separate layer in a DGN file, for each value of the attribute. The Dataset Fanout would create a separate DGN file, for each value of the attribute. You need a dataset fanout.

In the Navigator window in FME, check the parameters for the DGN writer. You'll see a parameter called Fanout Dataset. Double-click that and set the parameters, like so:

[image]

In this example I am converting a Shape dataset of cycle paths to DGN, and creating a separate DGN file for each different value of PathName.

You have to make sure you include the file extension in the Fanout Expression, as FME won't add it automatically.

When run, this is what I get for the output:

[image]

I hope that is what you are looking for. If not, please do respond and let us know.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I've seen the fanout option and thought this was only for the feature data. I use this to, to create extra layers into the DGN. But the filename with the dataset fanout is interesting.
Going to try this Tuesday when I'm back at the office after this Wit-weekend. And I keep you posted! W.k.rg.Paul